# Non admin profile with access to read and edit all objects

Tags: permission-sets, userrecordaccess, user-profile

Is it possible to give a user access to all objects (read and edit) but not allow them to do admin stuff like workflows, process builders, creating new permission sets or any other admin stuff except dat?

Do we have any standard profile that gives read & edit access to all objects and fields (just like admin) but not other data ?

Comment: You can clone the standard ``Read only`` profile and grant read/edit access to all objects.

Answer (score 0):

"workflows, process builders, creating new permission sets or any other admin stuff" are only accessible by System Administrators.

You need to clone a standard Profile and define the CRUD permissions to fit your need i.e read & edit access to all objects and fields. Your "General User Permissions" and "Administrative Permissions" should be limited for this new Profile. Do not grant **Customize Application** permission for this Profile.

[User capabilities with 'Customize Application' Profile permission](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000333124&type=1&mode=1).